# Why can I not get my first basic scatter plot to work?

Tags: plot, scatter, vega-lite

Can some friendly soul explain why this Vega config somewhat works, but as soon as I change x from nominal to quantitative, it doesn’t

```
{





“data”: {“values”:[

{“Pressure”:1,“Flow”:1},

{“Pressure”:2,“Flow”:2},

{“Pressure”:3,“Flow”:3}

] },

“mark”: “point”,

“encoding”: {

"x": {"field": "Presssure", "type": "nominal"},

"y": {"field": "Flow", "type": "quantitative"}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your chart contains a typo: your encoding is `"Presssure"` (with 3 `s` characters). If you change it to match the field in the data, your chart will work correctly ([view in vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUACgE7ZZonwCMANCAGIoD2A7lQL7WElZkVwBMtBi3j8OXUuQzwAzEKas4MtgF0OIALYQiAa3ggADowCWAOyghaGUwGNGYMwHN4oAB4uQAM2MYUYfcSSFLRQAJ4G0nAgAI5oEObGMFDGiNLqoR7evv5Rwqwh4ZExcQlJKWlsbEA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Pressure": 1, "Flow": 1},
      {"Pressure": 2, "Flow": 2},
      {"Pressure": 3, "Flow": 3}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Pressure", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "Flow", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You. Certainly helps with another set of eyes.